# How to get date in Scheme/Racket?

Tags: date, scheme, racket

I have been trying to write Scheme code to get the date and store the month in a variable, but have no clue how, even after reading the [online manual](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/time.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._current-seconds%29%29).

What I understand now is there is a struct called Date that needs 10 arguments, but not sure how to retrieve the month, or even date, from the library..could anyone please enlighten me on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it..

```
(let ((date (seconds->date (current-seconds))))
  (display (date-month date)))
```

working the manual took more effort than i thought.